# PostgreSQl,psql

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

Начал изучать PostgreSQl. У меня есть готовая база данных demo.sql как добавить ее? Нужно ли добавлять в PATH psql? для чего нужен SQL shell(psql)

Comment: Я юзаю прогу DBeaver, там все на изи...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

psql - это терминал для управления БД.
Если из командной строки windows psql не запускается, значит прописать в path (после прописки перезапустить командную строку, ПК, *переустановить window*s ;) )
Для импорта БД через терминал:

```
psql имя_базы < файл_дампа
```

[Восстановление дампа](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/12/backup-dump#BACKUP-DUMP-RESTORE)

[Restoring the Dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/backup-dump.html#BACKUP-DUMP-RESTORE)

Для удобного управления БД (в том числе для импорта дампа) можно использовать ПО pgAdmin.